# ANgularJs - Check all checkbox and Uncheck all checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing a functionality where the user, when selecting the first checkbox, all the others must be selected. When unchecking the first, all must be unchecked. And when the user selects the second checkbox, he must keep what he selected

What am I doing wrong because when I click on mark it is not marking all and the other way around. And I'm not able to retrieve the bookmark list.

My code

Controller

```
function checkAll() {
   vm.check = true;
   //Here check all
   vm.listCHeck.push(checkAll);
   if(vm.check == false) {
     unCheckAll();
   }
}

funcion unCheckAll() {
  vm.check = false;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
                <th>
                   Check
                </th>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                ng-model="vm.check"
                ng-click="vm.checkAll()">
            </td>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in list">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-click="vm.checkValueCHeckbox">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could you please share the structure of the list object and the method vm.checkValueCHeckbox

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the expression `if(vm.check == false)` will never be true with the code `vm.check = true` 3 lines above it.

```
 function checkAll() {
  vm.check = true;
  //Here check all
  vm.listCHeck.push(checkAll);
  if(vm.check == false) {
     unCheckAll();
  }
 }
```

Next problem, `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-click="vm.checkValueCHeckbox">`. The ng-model is based on whether checkAll is a truthy value or not. With the function existing, it's true.

Question, where's the block code for `vm.checkValueCHeckbox`?

I understand this is more of a comments and questions than an answer, but I'd like to help if more information was given. To at least assist a little, update the following code from `vm.check = true;` to `vm.check = !vm.check;` so that your value toggles from true to false and false to true as the user toggles the checkbox.